# Firebase database rules comparing key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I know that to compare with a keys value you would use `key.val() === something`. How would I compare the key of the new data being written to something, not the value but the key.

Comment: If you have a dynamic key, you'd identify that with a so-called `$` variable: e.g. `$uid` is a common variable used to identify user nodes `/users/$uid`. See this section in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#using_variables_to_capture_path_segments

Comment: Frank you're such a lifesaver, thankyou. Learning these firebase rules as a beginner is pretty difficult and having an active expert like you is priceless. I wish I could sit down with you and have you guide me through writing some rules haha, I would learn so fast!

Comment: Good to hear that this is what you were looking for Mark. I'm going to close to vote this question, since it's unlikely anyone will every find it when they're stuck in the same situation (even though there will be plenty of people with the same doubts about how to handle this case). If you get stuck again, just post back preferably with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found it.